# TypeError: registrationRules is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, function, rules

Help me understand what the problem is. When I start the project, an error comes up:
`TypeError: registrationRules is not a function at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\fenrir\Desktop\chat-app\chat-backend\router\auth.js:8:4) at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1083:30) at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1112:10) at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:948:32) at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:789:14) at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:19) at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:88:18) at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\fenrir\Desktop\chat-app\chat-backend\router\index.js:7:17) at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1083:30) at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1112:10) Program node index.js exited with code 1`

**auth.js:**

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const { login, register } = require('../controllers/authController')
const { validate } = require('../validators')
const { rules: registrationRules } = require('../validators/auth/register')

router.post('/login', login)

router.post('/register', [
    registrationRules(),
    validate
], register)

module.exports = router
```

**register.js:**

```
const {body} = require('express-validator')

exports.rules = () => {
    return [
        body('firstName').notEmpty(),
        body('lastName').notEmpty(),
        body('gender').notEmpty(),
        body('email').isEmail(),
        body('password').isLength({ min: 5})
    ]
}
```

Comment: You might be importing wrong file

Answer (score 1):

can you try this

```
const { rules as registrationRules } = require('../validators/auth/register')
```